# Get the ChildObject from the BaseObject

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

So i want to get the Secondobject

It's One to One from First.

### model.py(First)

```
class Firstobject(models.Model):
(...)       
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
   super().save(*args,**kwargs)
   Second.objects.get_or_create(first=self)
```

### model.py(Second)

```
class Votes(models.Model):
(...)
first = models.OneToOneField(First)     
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
   self.value2 = self.value - self.value2
   super().save(*args,**kwargs)      
   def __str__(self):
      return "%s name" % self.first
```

### View.py

```
def function(request, pk):
pk = request.GET.get('pk')
obj = models.First.objects.get(pk=pk)
votes = obj.Second
votes.value = votes.value + 1 
votes.save()
data = {'val1':votes.value, 'val2':votes.value2}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

### Index.html

```
<button 
data-url="{% url 'first:link' pk=first.pk %}" 
data-pk="{{first.pk}}"></button>
```

### foo.js

```
$('button').click(function() {
var pk = $(this).attr("data-pk"); 
var urla = $(this).attr("data-url"); //
$.ajax({
   url : urla,
   data : {'pk' : pk},
   success : function(data) {
      $('#ID1' + pk).text(data.val1)
      $('#ID2' + pk).text(data.val2)}
   });
});
```

So my **Error** is:

> AttributeError at /link/5/ 'First' object has no attribute 'Second'

I know whats the error is, but i cant figure out how to fix it.
The Error is in views.py. I cant just `First.Second`. So can you tell me what method i should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do add [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField)

```
first = models.OneToOneField(First, related_name="second")
```

Then you can do

```
obj = models.First.objects.get(pk=pk)
votes = obj.second
```

Answer (score 0):

To access a `onetoone` relationship in django you can access from the parent model class obj as such by referring it with the lower case name of its class unless an exclusive related_name is specified,

```
from django.db.models import F

obj = models.First.objects.get(pk=pk)
votes = obj.votes
votes.value = F('value') + 1
votes.save()
```

The F operator helps in such incrementations of values as it reflects the current state of the db.